# How to call a method when creating new ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to integrate an algorithm I wrote in pure Ruby into a Rails app. The main class of my Ruby project could be a resource.

When it was initialized in Ruby I immediately called a function in the `initialize` method:

```
def initialize(keyword)
  @keyword = keyword                    
  @sources = get_titles_of_sources                  
end
```

In Rails, when I create new objects I usually don't have or at least see a `initialize` method.

```
@user = User.new(attribute1: value1, attribute2: value2)
```

But this style doesn't allow me to automatically call a method when creating a new object.

Comment: do you want it to be triggered even when you fetch data from db?

Comment: just once, directly after initializing it.

Answer (score 5):

Given what you said in comments, I feel like you should avoid the callbacks (btw you should always avoid callbacks if you can...).

Anyway, I suggest you to create a `build` method like:

```
 class User 
   def self.build(props = {})
     new(props).tap do |user|
       #your code on initialize
     end
   end
 end
```

I usually tend to move `build` methods into builders. But it makes you create an additional `class`

Comment: Thx for your alternative solution. The problem with this is that I don't really understand what's going on in there. The `self.build` method overrides the `new` method or would I have to use `User.build` then?

Comment: yes you'd have to user `User.build({ attribute1: value1 })`

Comment: So why did you chose `build` over `new` or even `create`?

Comment: because using a different name lets you have your own method without overriding the existing. This way you dont surprise anybody and your code remains intention revealing

Answer (score 3):

Use `after_initialize` callback.

> Lastly an `after_find` and `after_initialize` callback is triggered for
>   each object that is found and instantiated by a finder, with
>   `after_initialize` being triggered after new objects are instantiated as
>   well.

[**Active Record Callbacks**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a use for `ActiveRecord Callbacks` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).